# How to translate object to vertice point?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I would like to have a object follow a predefined line(curve) in OpenGL ES. The easiest solution I have come up with is creating a circle and using the points(vertices) along the edge to guide the object. I'm lost as to how to use `translatem()`(using logical screen units) to locate the object from a vertex point though. I'm open to alternative solutions, but would prefer to keep the solution on the simpler side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get normalized screen coordinates through the following.

```
glSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event != null) {
                // Convert touch coordinates into normalized device
                // coordinates, keeping in mind that Android's Y
                // coordinates are inverted.
                final float normalizedX =
                (event.getX() / (float) v.getWidth()) * 2 - 1;
                //final float normalizedY = -((event.getY() / (float) v.getHeight()) * 2 - 1);//commented to kill z axis
                //final float normalizedY;

                final float scrnx =event.getX();
                final float scrny =event.getY();

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    normalizedY = -((event.getY() / (float) v.getHeight()) * 2 - 1);
                    glSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            airHockeyRenderer.handleTouchPress(
                            normalizedX, normalizedY);
                        }
                    });
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    normalizedY = -((event.getY() / (float) v.getHeight()) * 2 - 1);
                    glSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            airHockeyRenderer.handleTouchDrag(
                            normalizedX, normalizedY, scrnx, scrny);
                        }
                    });
                }
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

After translating the parent object, I use the x and z vertices of my parent circle which is laying flat on the z plane.

```
circPosition1.x = rcircle.vertexArray.rawFloatbuff[3*circcnter];
circPosition1.z = rcircle.vertexArray.rawFloatbuff[(3*circcnter)+2];
```

'rcircle' is the parent object.

'circcnter' is the position on the curve, or in this case circle.

'circPosition1' is the child object which will be located to the edge of the parent object.